# Http post byte data seen as text

Tags: http

I'm sending a post request with a zip. I'm able to communicate with the server, however the server interprets the data as plain text, not binary. I'm confused because declare that it's binary format: 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper content-type, the most generic fallback being `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: That doesn't do anything, nor does any of the other content-types. How do you know which one to pick?